# Permissions for a Bash Script

Tags: redhat

I have a script, located in /home/domain/cron/backup.sh

I basically want it to be CRON job that backs up the mysql database using mysqldump.  The command works find when I am logged in to the SSH, however when I want to run the file from the cron job it comes back permission denied.

The folder I want to dump to is called 'dbbackup'.  If I run `ls -al` on this folder I get:

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 root root 4096 Mar 16 14:07 ./
drwx--x--x 14 gf gf 4096 Mar 13 14:47 ../
```

`gf` is another user on the system, and is the user that the CRON script runs as.

When I run the CRON job, I get the following response:

`database2015-16-03-2015.sql: Permission denied`

I can only log in as a user called `graphite` to the SSH, the user `gf` does not have shell access so I cannot log in as them.

The mysqldump command is:

`mysqldump db_2015 > /home/gf/dbbackup/database2015-$(date +%d-%m-%Y)$`

I dont know what to do :(

**EDIT**
For future reference and anyone coming across the same frustration i was having, I found the solution, sort of.

Originally I was trying to set the cron job through the control panel, under the user `gf` (which is not one that has SSH access and therefore I cannot log into the command prompt with).  But of course this user does not have permissions to run this backup.sh file.

So I started thinking well the user that I created the backup.sh file with, `graphite`, maybe I can run the cron job as him.  So I started looking in to crontab, and still getting sudo errors (tty not found) and things.  Then I went back to my mysqldump command in the `backup.sh` file, and *instead* of starting that command with `sudo`, I ran it as normal, and placed the `-u <username> and --password=<password>` In there, and it works perfectly.  I've learnt a bit more about permissions and my database now backs up on a daily basis. Huzzah!

Comment: Can you print the permissions for the file itself?

Comment: Can you show the mysqldump command from the script please?  It's possible you're not sending the file to the place you think you are.

Comment: can you change any premissions on ur machine?

Comment: @Promination the file hasnt been made yet, so surely  can't set permissions for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is this :

```
drwx--x--x 14 gf gf 4096 Mar 13 14:47 ../
```

as you see `gf` can `read`, `write` and `excecute`, however other users can only `excecute`.

**Note** this is a `folder`. thus if its not `readable` the files inside can not be accessed.

what you need to do is to ensure this folder **and every other parent folder** is  `readable`. something like :

```
chmod 755 <folder name>
```

so you'll get:

```
drwxr-xr-x 14 gf gf 4096 Mar 13 14:47 ../
```

**NOTE** if you are not `root` or `gf` users. you won't be able to do any of those things.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was the problem.  But when I am logged in as someone **other** than `gf`, I don't seem to be able to change those permissions.

Comment: @Chud37 you created the dbbackup folder with root. can't you just access the previous folder as root too? **NOTE** root is able to do anything

Comment: no because command `mysqldump` is being run by a CRON job on the server under the user `gf`.

Comment: @Chud37 can you ssh to the server? if yes. then can you change user to either gf or root? if yes. then vola. you can do it .  else you can't do it

Comment: @Chud37 permission in linux are set for reasons. if any user could change other users setting then it would have been a chaos. (of course with exception of the root as it is the GOD)